# How to make a jQuery slider that will act like a volme control in a television

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to design a jQuery slider that will act like a volume control and change the color while it will grow to higher value.I am able to design that but my problem is that  the slider the changing manually but i want that i will supply some value on the basis of that value the slider will shrink or grow .
Here is a jsFiddle demo upto what i have got.

http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/133/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.checked').slider({

});
});
```

i want the slider to be changed upon input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/WqCkv/26/)

html

```
<section>   <span class="tooltip"></span> 
    <!-- Tooltip -->
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <!-- the Slider --> <span class="volume"></span> 
    <!-- Volume -->
</section>
```

jquery

```
$(function () {

    //Store frequently elements in variables
    var slider = $('#slider'),
        tooltip = $('.tooltip');

    //Hide the Tooltip at first
    tooltip.hide();

    //Call the Slider
    slider.slider({
        //Config
        range: "min",
        min: 1,
        value: 1,

        start: function (event, ui) {
            tooltip.fadeIn('fast');
        },

        change: function (event, ui) {
            var value = slider.slider('value');
            setVolumeImage(value);
        },

        //Slider Event
        slide: function (event, ui) { //When the slider is sliding

            var value = slider.slider('value');
            setVolumeImage(value);
            tooltip.css('left', value).text(ui.value); //Adjust the tooltip accordingly
        },

        stop: function (event, ui) {
            tooltip.fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });


    function setVolumeImage(value) {
        volume = $('.volume');
        if (value <= 5) {
            volume.css('background-position', '0 0');
            $(".ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header.ui-slider-range-min").css('background', 'green');
        } else if (value <= 25) {
            volume.css('background-position', '0 -25px');
            $(".ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header.ui-slider-range-min").css('background', 'yellow');
        } else if (value <= 75) {
            volume.css('background-position', '0 -50px');
            $(".ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header.ui-slider-range-min").css('background', 'orange');
        } else {
            volume.css('background-position', '0 -75px');
            $(".ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header.ui-slider-range-min").css('background', 'red');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can i input a value on the basis of that the slider will grow or shrink??

Comment: yes you can.. make a input box, take its value and make the value of slider equal to this value... let me do it..!

Comment: you can use `$("#inputValue").keyup(function () {` instead of `$("#inputValue").change(function () {` for realtime changing of the slider.

Comment: and one more thing  can i delete the volume sign??and also want to increase the size of the bar

Comment: yes remove the related codes from css and the jquery related to it.